# WINE Linux Debian Spotify Login Broken

Tags: linux, facebook, debian, spotify, wine

- Linux Debian OS Jessie
- WINE v 1.6.2
- Spotify installing and launching (ran .exe installation win)
- login not working (login wrong)
- cant link to facebook either 
  *Hey guys,* 
  I've recently started using a Linux system and I have downloaded the WINE programme to run Windows applications on my system. The fist programme I have tried to run is Spotify, and it worked! but, even though an icon in my programmes list is generated and it runs I cannot sign into my account and it continuously persists the the login details are wrong. this appears to be a reoccurring issue from what I've seen online but the issue is never publically resolved
  anyone else having this issue? 
  the site seems to think that Spotify is compatible?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run Spotify in wine unless you absolutely have to, meaning that you have an unsupported system or distro. Instead, you should use the native Linux client, for which Spotify has a debian package: https://www.spotify.com/se/download/linux/